# expected identifier before numeric constant in a Vector

Tags: c++

I am making a simple program, please take a look

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    int op=0;
    int v[20]=[1, 0];   
    float Ma=0;

    if (argv[1]==1)
    {
        float S=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
        {
            S=S+v[i];
        }
        Ma=(double)(S/20);
    }


    cout<<"Media aritmetica pentru elementele din vector este "<<Ma<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error Program.cpp:10:13: error: expected identifier before numeric constant

```
int v[20]=[1, 0];
         ^
```

I am using the gcc from ubuntu for compiling and I'm not really sure if there's anything to it that may cause this. I am a bit new into this.

Comment: It's not valid syntax. Where did you learn that this is how you initialize arrays?

Comment: I have learned C++ in highschool and some of it in my uni but I forgot a lot of it. I may have made a few mistakes or more :/

Comment: In that case you should consider [picking up a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), programming by guessing is not a good way to write code

Comment: `argv[1]` is not an int, it's a C-style string (pointer to a null-terminated sequence of characters). It makes no sense to compare it to 1 and your compiler should have warned you about that. It's a good idea to turn on all compiler warnings and read them every time you compile.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will look more into it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to define an array of 20 `int`'s and initialize its first 2 elements to 1 and 0 respectively.

Well, instead of writing:

```
int v[20] = [1, 0];
```

you should have written:

```
int v[20] = {1, 0};
```

which means what you want it to mean. Note, however, that the term "vector" has a different meaning typically in C++ - the name of the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container class in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces instead.

```
int v[20]={1,0};
```

Comment: Well, the other answer already suggests the same thing.

Comment: Well, he answered in the time that it took me to write mine is all.